# Why price changes on iTunesConnect are not being reflected on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to change the price of my app from $0.99 to free. I changed price tier to free on iTunesConnect and saved, but this is not affecting the price shown on the App Store for my app. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should wait some time before the change will appear on the App Store. Apple says it could take few hours for changes to appear correctly.

If things do not change after 24 hour you should contact the official Apple Support team.

Comment: Took about 4 hours in my case.

Answer (score 7):

Also, make sure you are following the advice on this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10917562/296446

> You need to set the schedule to 'Now' and 'None' (for start and end date) and then click the 'Add to schedule' button. Then save.