# Unable to change the Price tier in the In app Purchase

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, in-app-purchase, itunes, app-store-connect

I'm unable to change the price of an in-app purchase. I added initially for testing purposes, but now that I'm submitting the app, I'd like to change it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to accept the change. It is showing me the same price tier not the updated one.what should i do ?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I had this problem too. Here's how I solved it.

When you change the tier in iTunes Connect, it's not enough to then click 'done'. You need to set the schedule to 'Now' and 'None' (for start and end date) and then click the 'Add to schedule' button. Then save.

Cheers,

S

Comment: Yes, it's sooo weird.

Comment: Thanks Stew, I was going to create new ones.

Comment: Thanks stew you are an angel to me :)

Answer (score 16):

I found this especially confusing as the "Add to Schedule" button is disabled in my browser, even after selecting "Now" and "None". The button only becomes clickable after clicking on the background of the page to deselect the dropdown, which is probably firing some Javascript event that understands to enable the button.

Comment: I thought it may be disabled because my app is already in the wild..never would have done this. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Just to make it painfully clear (because I was still doing it incorrectly, even after reading Stew's answer above), here's a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot showing iTunes Connect screen for changing pricing tier]

You need to:

1. Select a tier.
2. Select options from the 'Price Effective Date' and 'Price End Date' menus (use Now and None for a price that's effective immediately and indefinitely).
3. **Click 'Add to Schedule' (it's easy to miss this step).**
4. Click 'Save'.

Answer (score 1):

This is now much simpler than it was when the question was asked originally. The Features page for your app at App Store Connect has a Plan a Price Change button under your in-app purchase, and when you press that, it’s very clear how to schedule a price change and make it take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone is here in 2020, but this is now in the "In-App Purchases" side menu. I tried twice scheduling a price change, and it didn't happen both times. I came here and saw there was something to do after you click "done", which is obviously much different now, but there is something else you need to do after you click "done". You need to also click "save" in the top right.